# Cocos2D deprecated animation methods

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I thought it would be appropriate to upgrade to XCODE5 and Cocos2D 2.x, but my code disagrees. I managed to find fix for most of my other code, but I can't seem to work this one out.

```
    - (CCAnimation *)createCatAnimation:(NSString *)animType
{
    CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animation];
    for(int i = 1; i <= 2; ++i) {
        [animation addFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] //addFrame: is deprecated 
spriteFrameByName:
                             [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cat_%@_%d.png", animType, i]]];
    }
    animation.delay = 0.2; //.delay is deprecated
    return animation;
}
```

How can I change this to be happy with deprecated stuff?

Comment: look in CCdeprecated.h and .m (.m implements the appropriate flavour of the day), so you can adapt your code.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg I found the file! :D And I have no clue what so ever to do with it! :D I'm a huge noob, so fool-proof instructions would be greeted with hugs and cake

Comment: as a "noob" don't upgrade to beta software, you're depriving yourself of many help resources while inviting new and as of yet unknown problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, i suspect that your getting 'warnings' about deprecatedeness of some methods, so your code works. Gives you some time to gain some un-noobiness and figure it out. But, just go inside a 'deprecated' method, you will see the 'right' way to code it. For example (from CCDepredated.m) , the method

```
-(void) addFrameWithTexture:(CCTexture2D*)texture rect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self addSpriteFrameWithTexture:texture rect:rect];
}
```

The top line IS the deprecated syntax. You get the warning for using it. However, at runtime, the top line is called and the RIGHT method is invoked at that time (enclosed in the method implementation). So you get the warning, but still works. Thus, to get rid of the warning, just locate all instances of the deprecated signature (top line), and replace with the new syntax (between the curly braces).

If like me you loathe having outstanding warnings when compiling, you will eventually find all instances of deprecated calls and fix them.

Comment: Animation.delay is errored, not just warninged. Same procedure? Thanks :)

Comment: unless you want to have a specific delay between any two frames, prefer to use the animation.duration property, for the total duration of the complete sequence.

Comment: Honestly, I took this code from some tutorial so long ago I have no idea what it even does anymore. But the animation is not a fixed time, it varies, so I guess .delay would be useful. Any tips?

Comment: Whatevs, screw that line. I'll come up with a workaround. Thanks  for the knowledge on deprecated stuff.